# Why are available updates of CKeditor not visible in the update report in Drupal 7?

Tags: updating

`/admin/reports/updates` lists a few updates, but the ckeditor module is missing here. It runs in version 1.9, since then a few security updates have been released, but it does not matter how often I run the cron or update the list manually, the updates for ckeditor wont be listed here.

The module itself works perfectly fine. How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the module's .info file was broken, downloading the 1.9 release and copying the .info file's content fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal only check for drupal modules. The CKEditor module is https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor and the latest version is 7.x-1.16. This information should appear in admin/reports/updates.

I suppose you are talking about the CKEditor library which is not handled by the page admin/reports/updates.

Comment: no, I mean the ckeditor drupal module, not the library's ckeditor folder.